# Can and how do I use multiple databases at the same time in SQL with the USE statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

My goal is to find the affected stored procedures across multiple databases when a table or view is updated. I am working in an environment with multiple databases where these stored procedures can exist. Below is a query that can do what I want for one database.

How can I achieve the results without having to change the USE statement to DatabaseB, DatabaseC, etc. or lengthy queries involving UNIONs?

```
USE DatabaseA

SELECT

        O.name
    ,   O.type_desc
    ,   M.definition

FROM sys.sql_modules M

LEFT JOIN sys.objects O
ON O.object_id = M.object_id

WHERE 1=1
    AND definition LIKE '%Error%'
```

I have played around with looping, but to no avail.

```
DECLARE name_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
OPEN name_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM name_Cursor;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM name_Cursor;
    END;
CLOSE name_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE name_Cursor;
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you took your existing cursor (from your second code sample), and you plugged your query (from your first code sample) in *as a dynamic query*, it should work:

```
SET @SQL = '
USE ' + @DatabaseName + '

SELECT

        O.name
...'
```

If you are wanting to run this query against ALL of your databases, a possibly easier solution would be to use the undocumented system stored procedure [sp_msforeachdb](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I know you are reluctant to use a UNION, but it can be helpful for your situation.  If you have the luxury of using Linked Servers, you can use a UNION with fully qualified paths. I would also recommend using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES if you can.

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM [DB1].[dbo].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%Error%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM [DB2].[dbo].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%Error%'
```

You can also used a memory optimized table approach:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/cross-database-queries

If you need to do something for each proc found, use this as the Cursor's SELECT statement.